# Eclipse shortcut to generate simple assignment in constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there anyway to generate the simple assignments from the constructor's parameters ?

From :

```
public class MyClass {

  public MyClass(String id, String name, String desc) {

  }

}
```

and with some magic shortcut, it will become :

```
public class MyClass {

  public MyClass(String id, String name, String desc) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
  }

}
```

and even better if we have the shortcut to generate into this (to avoid many 'ctrl + 1's to create the non existing fields):

```
public class MyClass {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String desc;

  public MyClass(String id, String name, String desc) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
  }

}
```

---

### update

I have found an acceptable way to deal with this :

First, my typical usage :

My constructor with the parameters are usually the output of ctrl + 1 from another class.

For example, in my code :

```
MyClass type = new MyClass("id", "name", "desc"); // the constructor doesnt exist yet
```

So, i ctrl + 1, create constructor, and tadaa, the constructor is created by eclipse

Now, to help my creating the fields and assigninig them values from the parameters, i just need to put the cursor on to the constructor parameter, **ctrl + 1 --> assign parameter to new field**, and repeat for all of the parameters.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't think there is any shortcut available for this in eclipse.

Comment: I think so too. This is one of the few physical exercises programmers can get these days, and should not be put into extinction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String desc;
}
```

If you type this much right click -> source -> generate constructor using fields

you can also generate all getters and setters.  I have set these up for hot keys once they do not have them by default.  But they require checking fields so it is not instant.

Comment: This approach is by far the nearest to what i intended, thanks !

Comment: I have found another way of doing this that is more suitable to my needs. Please see the update section in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Please see if it works.

Assign to local: Ctrl+2, L

Assign to field: Ctrl+2, F

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

1. Go to `Window`->`Preference`->`Java`->`Code Style`->`CodeTemplates`
2. Edit the constructor template to fit your requirement
3. Edit the class template and add a constructor var.

Then, when you create a new class, Eclipse will automatically add the constructor into your code.

Comment: But i dont really need the autogeneration of the constructor, since eclipse wouldnt know what parameters i need in the constructor. But what i rather need is for the eclipse to generate the assignment statements for me based on the constructor parameters i defined.

Comment: I just see how eclipse works: you can press alt+shift+s to call source menu, and select generate constructor with field, then you can select which field you want to assign.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

A popup will come up - click <kbd>ok</kbd> and the constructor of your class with fields will get generated.